# Can't connect to SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server

I have had lots of problems with SQL servers and have found a lot of solutions to any of my problems, but now it's something new. I have SQLEXPRESS running, but, when I connect, it says timeout. If I change the timeout period from 15 to 30, then after connecting 5s, the application becomes not responding and nothing else happens. The interesting part is, that everything was fine, I did not turn off the server and neither restarted the computer. It kind of happened from nowhere. Also I have firewall problem, that might somehow be related to SQL problem, because it happened almost at the same time. I have snap in problem and I can't see anything there. I am running windows server 2012 R2.

Any help would be highly appreciated, like any suggestions will work.
Also this might be pretty interesting to fix, since this is not the usual problem. If more information is needed, please ask in comments.

**EDIT**

The actual error is fallowing :

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to INSTANCE-1\SQLEXPRESS.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=20002; handshake=0;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

---

The wait operation timed out

Comment: [Configure a Windows Firewall for Database Engine Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx)

Comment: If your SQL Express is installed locally (it usually is), then firewall has nothing to do with it. First you need to go into Services and confirm that it is running. If it's running the next step is to try connecting to `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` and see what happens.

Comment: @Nick.MCDermaid It is running and when I try to connect to it, it throws error about connection timeout

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid also I have TCP/IP enabled, set the logon account to local system, tried to turn other mssql server off, if in case it was messing the sqlexpress up and I checked in cmd if the server name is correct

Comment: ok try to connect with the port number,localhost\SQLEXPRESS,1433

Comment: Are you connecting from an application or from SQL Server Management Studio? There is a good online guide to troubleshooting connectivity issues. I'll try to find it

Comment: I am connecting with SQL Server Management studio. @BeldiAnouar what would be the port number in the front? the tcp dynamic port or which one?

Comment: Just edited the question adding the error message

Answer (score 0):

Allowing Remote Connections for the SQL Database.
Enabling TCP/IP within the SQL Configuration.
specify the 1433 value in the TCP Port.

Please folow this [article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62165/i-cant-connect-to-my-servers-sql-database-via-an-ip-address) for more detail :

Comment: Remote connections are irrelevant for a local install